# Firewatir: firewatir returns undefined method error in eclipse

Tags: java, ruby, eclipse, watir, firewatir

Thank you for taking your time in reading this. I am just getting started with running Watir in Eclipse. When I try to load the `require 'firewatir'` statement on the top of the page, I receieve this error in the Eclipse console:

```
in `inherited': undefined method `demodulize' for "FireWatir::Pre":String (NoMethodError)
```

Running `require firewatir` in the 'irb' returns the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

System Information:
Ruby Version: Ruby 1.9.1p430
Eclipse Version: Eclipse Java EE IDE Build id: 20100218-1602
Watir Version: 1.6.5
FireWatir Version: firewatir 1.6.5

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by:

```
gem uninstall activesupport
gem install activesupport --version '=2.3.8'
```

To allow Watir to run on ruby 1.9.2
install devkit and follow procedures listed here : [Ruby Installer at GitHub](http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit)

```
gem uninstall win32-api
gem install win32-api --platform=ruby
```

Comment: I tried to create an account to open a bug on Jira twice. Found a bug with Jira, I guess. I'll try again later. Thanks for your attention to this in any case!

Comment: http://jira.openqa.org/browse/WTR-454
opened ticket WTR-454 per Charley's request.

Comment: Cliff, thank you for your reply. Adding require 'active_support'/inflector seem to work with eclipse. I was unaware of the uninstall function in ruby so thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a problem with the latest version of ActiveRecord - 3.0.0. I'd thought that we removed that as a dependency, apparently not. Please file a ticket in Jira and I'll take a look at it.

http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/FAQ#FAQ-HowtocreateaJiraTicket%3F

Comment: Charley, thank you for your reply. I'll definitely file a ticket on this matter if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

No need to uninstall activesupport-3.0.0, solved this by specifying required activesupport e.g:

```
require 'rubygems'    
gem "activesupport","=2.3.8"
require "firewatir"
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Watir does not work with Ruby 1.9. Install Ruby 1.8.

Comment: Zeljko, thank you for your suggestion. I was using Ruby 1.9 and you were correct, it did go over so well. Currently trying the Ruby 1.8 version right now.

Comment: There are versions of watir that work with ruby 1.9, but I did not want to get you confused.